# codeigniter 3.1.7 session not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to set a session in codeigniter 3.1.7 but its not properly working.

When I do this

```
function test(){
   $params = array(
       'test' =>'worked',
       'base_url'=> base_url(),
       'temperture' => 23,
       'cart_length'=>'7 items'

   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($params);

   print_r( $this->session->all_userdata());
   // prints data no problem
}

function redirect(){
   print_r( $this->session->all_userdata());
   //prints Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1521089504 )
}
```

config settings

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'centrl';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 1800;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
```

I can't understand how in the actual function it sets the session but it seems to remove it when going to another function.

Comment: Why do you set the _sess_driver_ to _null_?

Comment: Make sure you have set the session save path don't leave it null

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set a data into session in CI

```
$session_data = array(
'admin_email' => $result[0]->email_id,
'Admin' => TRUE,
'user_id' => $result[0]->id
);

// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

This is how you can access Session values

```
 <?php echo  $this->session->userdata('admin_email');?>
```

P.S Keep the config settings untouched, you don't need to modify it.

Comment: yes i understand how to set them and i appreciate what your saying  however if i print out the session right after setting it it displays the data  from the session but then if i go to another function and try the same print of the session it  returns  Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1521084001 )

Comment: its like the session is bbeing set then automatically unset

Comment: pls try my example and just replace my values with your values and print it , it will work, you need to print the session array, you are not setting it in proper way so

Comment: its still the same outcome  it prints off session in the function i set it in  but in another function  Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1521084001

Answer (score 0):

[Set this `files`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L370-L376)

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

and use below code to set session

```
$newdata = array(
        'base_url' => base_url()     
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

**Note:** Make sure [**session library is loaded in CI**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session) (in config/autoload.php or function itself).

Comment: its still the same works when printing off in same function bbut when printing in another function Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1521089340 ) thats with it changed to files in config also autoloading in autoload.php

Comment: No way. you're doing something wrong then. CI session is easiest one ever i used. post your complete controller code

Comment: function test(){
                       

                        
           
           $params = array(
               'test' =>'worked',
               'base_url'=> base_url(),
               'temperture' => 23,
               'cart_length'=>'7 items'
               
           );
            $this->session->set_userdata($params);
            
            print_r( $this->session->all_userdata());
           
          
        }
        function redirect(){
           
            
           print_r( $this->session->all_userdata());
        }

Comment: add in your question

Comment: could it be something to do with server configuration i'm using it on vps